# How to set HTML Audio or Video Thumbnail and Title on chrome media control menu and in windows media control dialog

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio

How to make thumbnail and title of audio or video in html visible in chrome media control menu and in windows media control menu (dialog appears on volume up or down key pressed)

**Chrome Menu**

[image]

**Windows Media control Menu**

[image]

**Possible Thoughts:-**

1. may be some meta attribute to acheive this?
2. or playing with https://schema.org/MusicRecording?

Answer (score 6):

After digging some time, found a solution in developers.google.com web updates.

**Result:-**

[image]

**To Acheive this:-**

Refer:- [Media Session](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session)

[image]